# odometry on arduino vs on ROS

Tags: arduino, navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have got an arduino connected to my robot that reads the encoder and controls the motors.

What would be better, calculating odometry on arduino and publishing the odometry message to ROS on my Laptop?

Or publishing the encoder ticks to ROS and publishing the odometry messages after processing from Laptop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199027/odometry-on-arduino-vs-on-ros/) by [HassanNadeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/20965/hassannadeem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2020-02-24**:
I want to do the same thing too. Could you please share the arduino and python code (ros code) about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In most cases it's better to count the ticks on the arduino and sending the integrated values over ROS topics.

Counting encoder ticks is something which microcontrollers are quite good at.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1